# how to release Dynamically created View id and re-assign to another view

Tags: android, user-interface

I have some dynamic views that generate at run-time. for save their  data in fragment I had to put each of them an unique ID. cause on replace fragment onSaveInstance do not called.
so I created some IDs in xml and then assign to created views and android handle views data when they pop from stack.

the problem is views are cascade and very dynamic and IDs in xml  are limited.  so I want to know how I can release views ID after it's gone to re-assign to another View. or is it better way to save this dynamic view state and data?

Comment: There's no need to "release" them, per se. Just make sure you don't have multiple `View`s with the same ID in the same hierarchy at a time.

Comment: You can handle anything with just a Bundle.  How do you think android is handling it for you?  With a Bundle.

Comment: @GabeSechan check this article: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en it say that it is beter to handle view state by itself.

Comment: @MikeM. my view is cascaded so changing one cause to change many views.

Comment: @Kenji I can write a random blog post that says you should give me all you money.  When will I get my check?  That's probably a good idea for static views, but its a bad idea for dynamic ones.

Comment: @Kenji side note:  put even less faith in blog posts written in bad english.  I understand its not every programmers first language, but messy output is usually a sign of messy logic.

Answer (score 0):

Ids are limited to an integer.  Unless you're making millions, I wouldn't worry about it.  I also don't think that's a good way to save their state though-  you're better off putting it into the Bundle in onSaveInstanceState by hand.